# Unity meta file stored in specific folder

Tags: c#, git, version-control, metadata, unity-game-engine

I'm having some problems versioning meta files in Unity. I have common code that I share between my different projects (as git submodules) and they affect some GameObject differently in each projects. Each projects generate different meta files from my common code. That's where the problem is.

If I version the meta files (in my common code), I end up with the same meta files in all my project which is obviously not what I want because the behavior might be different. One of the solutions I found would be to store the meta files related to my common code somewhere in every projects so they stay specific to one project and doesn't affect others. I can't find any information about this.

**My question is : is there a way to store meta files in a specific folder and link them to the scripts of another folder?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, what I did was : I now have a script that copies meta files into my specific project so I can commit them. Then, when you clone the repo, there is another script that copies them back into my submodule. That way, my scene loads correctly. It's not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can refer below:

So you treat the different projects as submodules for the common code? If so, you can store meta files to the different projects’ subfolder, and these meta files can be controlled version separately.

Comment: My statement wasn't clear, my bad. Actually, my common code is a submodule in every git project I have.

Comment: Also you can store the meta files in the directory of each git project, because of the different directories, these meta files are also treat differently by git.